# Making -std=c++11 the default in mac terminal

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, c++11, terminal

When I want to compile, I need to specify `-std=c++11` like this:

```
g++ -Wall -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main
```

and I wonder if there was a solution to set the -std=c++11 flag permanently so it will be possible to do:

```
 g++ -Wall main.cpp -o main
```

without flags.

Comment: `alias g++='g++ -std=c++11'`?

Comment: Another solution would be patching GCC so that it includes some fresher/more sensible options than defaulting to a 15 years old standard...

Comment: patching ?

Otherwise, the alias works fine, thanks.

Comment: Made that an answer then. Yes, I'd even consider patching it (the GCC that ships with OS X is ancient...)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by patching ? ( sorry i'm not english ^^ ).

Otherwise i upgraded with macport the last gcc version

Comment: I am not English either. Google it. Or look it up in a dictionary.

Comment: or you could just create a makefile like you should be doing anyway for c++ and c

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create an alias: `alias g++='g++ -std=c++11'` should do the trick.

(However, the version of GCC that comes with OS X is so ancient that it doesn't support C++11, you'd be better off using `clang` and `clang++`.)

Comment: Hum concerning clang :

clang --version
Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.0
Thread model: posix

but I don't know how to use it

Comment: @Choubidou Well, just as you would use GCC. (But hey, can't you just google "clang usage"? Or "clang manual"? Or type `clang --help` into the command line?)

Comment: @Choubidou on a mac if you want it to be permanent you should put it in your `.bash_profile`

Answer (score 5):

I know this already has an accepted but I feel like I have some advice to offer. For one you should be using a makefile for c++, this is the one I use for answering on SO.

```
CFLAGS=-std=c++11 
CFLAGS+=-stdlib=libc++
CC=clang++
#flags for test.c
cc=clang
DEBUG=-g
#warnings
WARNINGS=-Weverything
#always have -Weverything on for SO lol
OPT= -O0 -O1 -O2 -O3 -O4

test: test.cpp
    $(info set CC for compiler)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ $(DEBUG) 

stack: stack.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) stack.cpp -o $@ $(DEBUG) $(WARNINGS)

testc: test.c
    $(cc) $< -o $@ $(DEBUG) 


clean:
    rm test
```

Now whenever I download someones crappy code from SO I have a makefile for c and c++ files where I can easily change the flags if I want to.

As for bash alias I would suggest you alias it like so `alias clang++11='clang++ -std=c++11` this way you don't overwrite the `clang++` if you don't want to use the c++11 standard. Lastly you can add the line I just showed you to your `.bash_profile` on a mac which is in your home or `~` folder, this will make the change permanent. Once you change it run `source .bash_profile` to put the changes into effect. On linux I think the file is called `.bashrc`. Hopefully these tips will help you out when ur c++ing, I would advise you to learn the mac command line, has differences from the linux one, it can be very useful to know some of the things it can do.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here's another thing that was happening for me– I used `alias g++='g++ -std=c++20'`
But this worked only for the ongoing terminal session. If I were to start up another one, it would not work.

The workaround to this I found was to go to `~/.zshrc`.
The original zshrc file was:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/arnavmangla/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/arnavmangla/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/arnavmangla/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/arnavmangla/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

added the alias command here and the new zshrc is:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/arnavmangla/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
alias g++='g++ -std=c++20'
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/arnavmangla/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/arnavmangla/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/arnavmangla/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

Now whenever I open new sessions of terminal, the version being used in C++20

PS: This is some code I found to check the C++ Version:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
int main() {
    if (__cplusplus == 202002L) std::cout << "C++20\n";
    else if (__cplusplus == 201703L) std::cout << "C++17\n";
    else if (__cplusplus == 201402L) std::cout << "C++14\n";
    else if (__cplusplus == 201103L) std::cout << "C++11\n";
    else if (__cplusplus == 199711L) std::cout << "C++98\n";
    else std::cout << "pre-standard C++\n";
}
```

Comment: Hint: Conda already used `<<<` `>>>` to **nicely** seperate its own environment config from your own stuff. So don't wrap them together in case one day you might need modification which may cause env bugs.  Just add to the top or bottom will do the trick, or simply use the command `echo "alias clang='clang -std=c++11'" >> ~/.zshrc`.