# Set as default C++11 in Clang

Tags: c++11, clang, standards

The LLVM C++ compiler has full support for C++11 standard. Is there a way to set C++11 as the default standard without adding `-std=c++11` compiler flag every time? I tried setting `CCXFLAGS` environment variable to `-std=c++11`, but with no luck.

Comment: To start with the environment variable should be `CXXFLAGS`, and I'm not sure that clang even checks it?

Comment: You say CCXFLAGS. Is this a typo in your question ? It should be CXXFLAGS.

Comment: [This would do that for you but there must be better answers:][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18040048/making-std-c11-the-default-in-mac-terminal

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I enable C++11 in gcc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16886591/how-do-i-enable-c11-in-gcc)

Comment: "LLVM C++ compiler has full support for C++11 standard". That is not actually quite true. Clang++ on Linux uses GNU's libstdc++ (by default), at it does not yet fully complies to the c++11 standard. BTW: CXXFLAGS is for Makefiles, not the compiler.

Comment: Don't use `CXXFLAGS`, use `CXX` for dialect options, as these may affect the linker as well, e.g., `CXX="clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++"` - invoke it on the command line with `$CXX`, and let build tools pick up `CXX`.

Answer (score 1):

Use clang 6.0.0 or higher. The default C++ dialect is now C++14.

http://releases.llvm.org/6.0.1/tools/clang/docs/ReleaseNotes.html#c-language-changes-in-clang

Answer (score 0):

You could add `alias clang='clang -std=c++11'` to `~/.bash_profile` using this command:

```bash
echo "alias clang='clang -std=c++11'" >> ~/.bash_profile
```