# Did a compiler ever resolve namespace ambiguities?

Tags: c++, c++11, tokumx

I have to compile the code of tokumx from percona's github repository. It contains an [ambiguity](https://github.com/percona/toku2mongo/blob/a052dd94958b01a5ff95812b3368c93aec056d0b/src/mongo/pch.h#L61) regarding [the use of `shared_ptr`](https://github.com/percona/toku2mongo/blob/a052dd94958b01a5ff95812b3368c93aec056d0b/src/mongo/tools/toku2mongo.cpp#L211) .

In short, the pattern is as follows:

```
namespace baz
{
    class integer;
}

namespace bar
{
    class integer;
}

namespace foo
{
    using namespace bar;
    using baz::integer;
}

namespace main
{
    using namespace foo;

    void f(const integer&);
}
```

Naturally, this won't compile. And I am not here to ask why, but rather to understand how this *ever compiled in the first place* and if I can trust that codebase at all. That code is from 2014 and C++11 was definitely a thing back then. My suspicion is that this code was never compiled with C++11 simply because the compilers did not default to that standard 5 years ago, is that correct?

1. When (which gcc/clang version) was C++11 the default?
2. Is there some magic compiler flag that would resolve the issue even with C++11?
3. Now to the bonus question: If that software was never compiled with C++11 is it even safe to patch that particular spot or do I risk invisible changes in behavior that can lad to severe runtime errors? (By *invisible* I mean errors that do not occur at compile-time but rather changes in behavior that lead to errors at runtime like memory leaks or crashes.)

Comment: `std::shared_ptr` didn't exist before C++11.

Comment: I know. That's why I am asking when it became the default.

Comment: GCC 6.0 according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21221411/when-will-gnu-c-support-c11-without-explicitly-asking-for-it). And Clang 6.0 also, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21581838/set-as-default-c11-in-clang). Clang 6.0.0 came out on 8th March 2018. (Although Clang was C++11 feature complete on 19 April 2013).

Comment: C++11 is not the default in any GCC version.

Comment: That's also why `using namespace std;` in header is **bad**.

Comment: *"is it even safe to patch that particular spot"* Depends how you fix it, but qualify each `shared_ptr` should be safe (as you didn't mix them). Removing the `using namespace` might introduce subtle bug if there is an overload with better match in `std`.